# Jenkins : Cannot run program "hg"

Tags: java, ubuntu, mercurial, jenkins

Although if I log in at command line as myself `hg` does work.

I assume I need to set the "mercurial installation directory" as part of the configure jenkins process.

However I do not know what my mercurial installation directory is, I followed the instructions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Installing_Mercurial).

Comment: What OS is this on, you could run `which hg` command if it's a *NIX.

Comment: if you have the `locate` command installed, you could use that to find mercurial's installation directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the command line when you are logged in, just do

```
 which hg
```

This will print the exact path to the `hg` executable which you can use to setup Jenkins.

For example, on Debian, and on most of current Linux distribution, this would be :

```
$ which hg
/usr/bin/hg
```